# Haskell partial type comparison

Tags: haskell

Ive been trying to make a function for displaying the reduced data type of simple lambda calculus given a context. For this I need to compare a type of format

```
a :-> b
```

to a type of format

```
a
```

I havent been able to find a way of partially comparing the types of data like this, i.e. checking whether the type of one thing contains the type of another. If there's a simple way to do this I cant seem to find it online.
These types are generic and can be anything (e.g. a could be (Foo :-> Bar) :-> Int or anything really, which is why I cant just use a base type)

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking here. In what context are you checking this? What happens when the check fails? What happens when it succeeds? Haskell's usual model is that if the types don't fit together it fails to compile, and after compilation the types have been erased. Are you talking about compile-time checking or some sort of runtime checking? If you're doing something at runtime, where are the types coming form?

Comment: im checking like this, I have a function which contains  (typeof x n == Foo :-> Bar) && (typeof x m == Foo). I dont particularly care what Foo or Bar are and they will change depending on what is input into the function. I am just not sure how to do type comparison pattern matching like this within the function. Im sorry if its unclear. @Carl

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on exactly what you want, but suppose it were like this:

```
data Type baseTypes = Type baseTypes :-> Type baseTypes | Base baseTypes
```

Then you could write something like:

```
funCallCompatible :: Eq b => Type b -> Type b -> Maybe (Type b)
funCallCompatible (a :-> b) a' = if a == a' then Just b else Nothing
funCallCompatible _ _ = Nothing
```

Is that the kind of thing you're talking about?

For a more advanced treatment of typechecking, you'll want to read about unification. Google should help get you started. I can also strongly recommend the book Types and Programming Languages.

Comment: I do have a data type declaration quite similar to that with `data Type = Base | Base :-> Base`, will a declaration like this work for a similar formatting of function? As ive edited the function youve kindly provided to fit my type declaration but it seems to always return nothing

Comment: I.e. my new version of the funCallCompatible function takes types `Type -> Type -> Bool` and returns either True or False as opposed to a type or Nothing. It also already derives Eq so im not sure if I need the `Eq b =>` part at the beginning? @DanielWagner

Comment: @gmandonnan If you want help with a chunk of code you've written, you have to show us the code you've written. Open a fresh question with full details -- the code, what input you try, what output you expect, what output you actually get -- and I (and many others) will be happy to take a look at it.